# How to Increase jqGrid toolbar / navbar icon size for visual accessibility?

Tags: jquery, datagrid, jqgrid, struts2, accessibility

Here is a requirement that we received, can we increase the size Struts2-jQuery Grid /jQGrid  'Toolbar Icons' ? like Save/Delete/Find/Add etc ?

> Our users would need visual accessibility in this regard. Is there any
>   solution apart from setting the zoom size of the browser ?

Update (How we fixed it):

Step 1: [Downloaded](http://www.tnghardware.com/sandbox/jQueryIconTests/nameTable.html) a 32px icon sprite grid  
Step 2: Placed this sprite grid image in the webapp\template\mytheme\images folder  
Step 3: Updated the `jquery-ui.css` file (which was generated for our custom theme from ThemeRoller) 
Step 4: In the ICONS section update the `.ui-state-default` class to point the new image  
Step 5: Added `width: 16px; height: 16px;`  properties to the same class  
Step 6: Adjusted the position in every image classes  
Step 7: We used image editing tools to compress it's size so that we could make all icons from 32px to 24px and varied the color settings (Hue/Saturation..etc) to get different colors for various UI states.

```
 example: 
Changed
.ui-icon-trash { background-position: -176px -96px; }

to 

.ui-icon-trash { background-position: -352px -192px; }
```

This brought the new sized icons.The only challenge we face now is to find a suitable 32px css sprite grid icon image for various states (Active, Default, Hover and Error).

It would have been great if ThemeRoller has this option to generate icon set of various sizes.

Comment: Where is the download link for the 32px icon sprite grid?

Comment: Here it is http://www.tnghardware.com/sandbox/jQueryIconTests/nameTable.html  and i got this from this discussion in jQuery UI WiKi  http://www.tnghardware.com/sandbox/jQueryIconTests/nameTable.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to download a new set of icons which are available in 32px, these icons come along with jquery ui custom css.

check this link for further help

http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/26308090/ThemeRoller-icon-set

Comment: thank you for your reply.. Is there any other changes we have to do after placing the 32px icon set ? Any property file or something we should change so that the jQuery widgets starts using the new sized icons ?

Comment: u need to download the image which is 32px pixel aligned and replace the old image file which came with custom jquery ui css with this one...your application will directly pick those icons

Comment: it worked like a charm.. thank you.. now we are searching for 24px or 32px icons in an "css sprite grid". thanks again :-)