# Prevent row becoming editable during double click - jqGrid

Tags: jquery, datagrid, jqgrid

Ours is a Struts2-jQuery Grid implementation , it is similar to jqGrid. We have made our Grid as

```
multiselect="true" and editinline="true"
```

We have added 'Custom Edit' buttons in each row's data and want the row to become editable only via that. We have removed the navbar/tool bar icons for 'Edit'.

Currently, the data row becomes editable even during a double click on the row. We are able to capture the event, but how to cancel out the action ? we tried returning false, stop.. but they did not work. We even tried stop.propogation and still the row was becoming editable.

How can we stop this ?

Comment: did u try my answer? did it work?

Answer (score 0):

add this to your jqgrid along with other parameters

```
ondblClickRow: function(){
  return false ;
},
```

OR using jquery u can bind double click event (ondblClickRow) to you grid and return false from that function.

Comment: we are going to try it now..  do you mean we have attach/bind this function to the entire grid ?

Comment: okay there are two methods ...first you write this code along with other parameters where you write all jqgrid parameters like colModal, colName, pager or you can bind this with $("#grid").bind("ondblClickRow", function(){return false;});....like this also..i hope this works for you.